# How to debug HTML file in Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, html, html5

I am new to Lightning Web Components. I created a LWC that will search for accounts and display the account name. Initially, I was not able to display data in html file because I was using `{acc.name}` instead of `{acc.Name}`. I was not able to debug and check value of this variable as it was in HTML file. In such cases, how can I debug HTML file and check value of variables? Is it even possible?

I tried to use `<script> console.log(acc.name) </script>` inside HTML file but it gives me the error `Forbidden tag found in template: '<script>' tag is not allowed.` I cannot use `<script>` outside of `<template>` tag as it gives me error `Multiple roots found lwc`.

[image: Screenshot of component]

> **HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account-list" icon-name="standard:account">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input  label="Find Account" value={searchKeyAcc} onchange={handleChangeAcc} class="slds-m-bottom_small">
            </lightning-input>
            <template for:each={accounts} for:item="acc">                   
                <lightning-layout-item key={acc.id}>
                    <p>{acc.Name}</p></br><!--Error Here-->
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
            <lightning-button label="Find Account" variant="Brand" onclick={findAccounts}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

> **JavaScript**

```js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccList from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController1.getAccountList';


export default class AccountSearch extends LightningElement {
    @track searchKeyAcc;
    @track accounts;
    @track errorAccount;

    handleChangeAcc(event){
        
        this.searchKeyAcc = event.target.value;
    }
    findAccounts(){
        getAccList({
            name:this.searchKeyAcc
        }).then(result=>{
            this.accounts=result;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.errorAccount=error;
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HTML and Javascript are cAsE sEnSiTivE.

The only way to debug is through javascript (you cannot really do anything in HTML).

```
    getAccList({
        name: this.searchKeyAcc
    }).then(result => {
        this.accounts = result;
        console.log('accounts => ', JSON.stringify(this.accounts));
    })
        .catch(error => {
            this.errorAccount = error;
        })
```

Here you will get the exact data structure (array `[]`) and the API names. And you need to use the exact API names in HTML also to render correctly.

**Even for any other use cases you need to put debuggers and console statements in strategic lines to understand what is being passed to HTML.**

Answer (score 1):

If you check your browsers devtools, all your components will be available in `../modules/c`.  There you can add breakpoints and debug as you normally would.  Turn on debug mode for your user to see the unminified versions of your code.